# get the product list from wp estore plugin

Tags: e-commerce

I am working to get the product list from wp estore and show in custom plugin,i have done this for woocommerce but i have searched alot for wp estore but no success

this code i have done for woocommerce is

```
<?php 
   $args = array(
      'posts_per_page' => 5,
      'post_type' => 'product'
   );
?>
<form action ="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" method ="POST">

   <?php $products = new WP_Query( $args );?>
   <select name="test">
   <?php
      foreach ( $products as $product ) {
          $products->the_post();

          ?><option name="state" id="state"> <?php the_title(); ?>
          <?php
      }
   ?>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>

<?php
   if($_POST['submit']) {
      global $wpdb;
      $table_name ='wp_hassan';
      $state = $_POST['test'];
      $success = $wpdb->insert("wp_hassan", array(
         "productname" => $state,
      ));

      if($success) {
         echo ' Inserted successfully';
      } else {
         echo 'not';
      }
  }
```